# Set a configuration with a condition Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I need to set a configuration in Databricks SQL unity catalog.
I tried with the IF function like

```
IF ( "${filetype}" = 'Full' , SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions =1000)
```

The python syntax for what I want to achieve is.:

```
IF filetype = "Full":
   spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",1000)
```

I need to achieve this python if condition in Databricks SQL notebook with the runtime 13.3 LTS